# gcloud: Default Application Credentials in appengine for Cloud Storage (java)

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm having difficulty with authentication when accessing Google Cloud Storage from within an appengine web app. I want to use the Application Default Credentials. Maybe someone can advise me.

I have a project, with service account: "x@appspot.gserviceaccount.com".

In section IAM the project has only member, y@gmail.com (which is my email address), with role Owner.

In the project I have two Cloud Storage buckets, staging.x.appspot.com and x.appspot.com. I haven't edited their permissions.

In the project I have an appengine web app written in Java. From its code, I want to access Cloud Storage like this:

```
    import com.google.cloud.AuthCredentials;
    import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage;

    AuthCredentials credentials=AuthCredentials.createApplicationDefaults();
    Storage storage=StorageOptions.builder().authCredentials(credentials).build().service();
```

with maven dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.38</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-auth-library-appengine</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>gcloud-java</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

I start the development server with

```
mvn clean appengine:devserver
```

and deploy with

```
mvn clean appengine:update
```

I would have thought that is enough.

But in devserver on one computer it works, on another computer I get exception "401 Invalid authentication" or something like that. I don't know what the difference between the computers is.

In the deployed app I get exception 403 Forbidden.

Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Forbidden",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Forbidden"
}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Per https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials#toolsupport, application default credentials should work fine when running on App Engine itself, but may only work locally by default if you start Appengine with "gcloud preview app run". Alternately, try running `gcloud auth login` before running your sample.

Comment: ^^ echo this. You'll need to run `gcloud auth login` or `gcloud auth activate-service-account` ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/)) before default credentials will work in dev.

Comment: Any updates on this thread?

Comment: Well, I went to the bucket configuration and explicitly added permission for User "x@appspot.gserviceaccount.com" with Access "Writer". With that my application works, but I'm not closing the question because I thought that should have been automatic, so maybe I'm still doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As Brandon and Nick said, `gcloud auth login` with the google user that is the owner (so not the service account) did the trick. Thanks for your help.